# React + Chai + Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, chai, enzyme

I'm trying to run some unit test with Chai&Enzyme to my React app.

Enzyme seems to have an issue with props I passed to components. They got undefined in tests (not in app).

main file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import TaskList from './components/task_list';
import AddingInput from './components/input';

const titleHeader = <h1 className="app__title">Simple to-do list:</h1>;

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tasks: [
                {id: 0, name: 'Complete task'},
                {id: 1, name: 'Add task'},
                {id: 2, name: 'Delete task'}
            ],
            id: 3,
        };
    }

(...)

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="app">
        {titleHeader}
        <TaskList
            tasks={this.state.tasks}
            deleteMe={this.deleteMe.bind(this)} />
        <AddingInput addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Task_list - first component I want to test:

```
import React from 'react';
import TaskItem from './task_item';

const TaskList = (props) => {
    const taskItems = props.tasks.map((task) => {
        return (
            <TaskItem
                key={task.id}
                task={task}
                deleteMe={props.deleteMe}
                />
        );
    });

    return (
        <ol className="ordered-list">
            {taskItems}
        </ol>
    );
};

export default TaskList;
```

And the second:

```
import React from 'react';

const TaskItem = React.createClass({
  onCompleted: function(e) {
    e.target.className += " ordered-list__item--completed"
  },
  render: function() {

    return (
        <li><span className="ordered-list__item" onClick={this.onCompleted}>{this.props.task.name}</span>
            <span onClick={() => this.props.deleteMe(this.props.task)}
                  className='btn btn--delete'>Delete</span>
        </li>
    );
  }
});


export default TaskItem;
```

An here are my tests. Two of them are passed (both component exist) but in other two got undefined on `props.tasks`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect, assert } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import TaskList from './src/components/task_list';
import TaskItem from './src/components/task_item';

describe('TaskList', () => {
    it('should render TaskItem', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<TaskList />);
        expect(wrapper.containsAllMatchingElements([
            <TaskItem />,
        ])).to.equal(true);
    });
    it('should exists', () => {
        assert.isDefined(TaskList)
    })
});
describe('TaskItem', () => {
    it('should render one item of unordered list', () => {
        const item = mount(<TaskItem />);
        expect(item).to.contain('li');
    });
    it('should exists', () => {
        assert.isDefined(TaskList)
    })
});
```

Problems:
 1) TaskList should render TaskItem:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
 2) TaskItem should render one item of unordered list:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `App` component passes a `tasks` prop:

```
<TaskList
    tasks={this.state.tasks}
    deleteMe={this.deleteMe.bind(this)} />
```

And `TaskList` expects it to be always present.  Similarly, `TaskItem` expects to always have certain props available (from `TaskList`).

If you add the necessary props in your unit tests, it should work.  For `TaskList`, this might look something like the following (untested):

```
const tasks = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Complete task'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Add task'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Delete task'}
];
const wrapper = shallow(<TaskList tasks={tasks}/>);
```

Comment: That was the thing I missed! Thank you :)